# tailwindCss : how to use lg-px-4

Tags: tailwind-css

i want use px-4 for footer only

lg:px-4

but it does not work

```
<footer class="footer py-5 text-white bg-gray-800">
<div class="flex flex-col  items-center justify-between lg:flex-row  max-w-6xl mx-auto 
lg:space-y-0 space-y-3">
<div class="space-x-4  lg:px-4">
<a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon-brand-instagram text-lg  text-white text-opacity-75  text-md hover:text-white"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

[My sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzm1N.png)

Comment: Maybe your screen is not above 1024px

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) docs, the `lg` prefix value is for screens large than 1024px.
So, if your screen size is less than 1024 px, you probably will not see the effect.
A quick zoom out in your browser can give an idea if the padding is applied or not.

You also can change this default value by using [custom breakpoints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#customizing-breakpoints) in your `tailwind.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

px will specify the padding horizontally

and lg specifies the break point for responsive screen

lg  = 1024px    @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

its not working maybe because of your screen size. try to open it in dev tool of chrome and change screen size and take it below/above 1024. it will work